# Ring formation via oxymercuration-demercuration

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I'm solving past problems from a 2014 Organic Chemistry II course (from a publicly available Harvard summer school Canvas page), when I came across this question:

[image]

The answer (which is the reactant) looks like this:

[image]

Now I understand how the alkyne would turn into an alkene, but I don't get how a furan would form from what looks like an oxymercuration-demercuration reaction. Any help would be much apprecited.

Answer (score 3):

Observe that there is no nucleophile give in the mercuration step and recall that the three-membered mercury ring intermediate is very reactive. Hence, this is suggestive that the oxygen would attack the intermediate with its lone pair on the more substituted position as follows:

[image]

Edit: Oops! Missed a carbon on the last step as correctly pointed out by @Waylander. I have updated the answer with a new image that corrects the mistake.

---

For reference see  Addition reactions of Alkene's in David Kleins organic chemistry (around page-410 ) and for a quick reference see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymercuration_reaction)

Comment: You are missing a carbon in the final structure - otherwise this looks correct